# Why does Oracle still not support Multi-Row insert?

Tags: oracle

According to [Wikipedia's article about INSERT in SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_%28SQL%29#Multirow_inserts), multi-row inserts are standard since SQL-92. Oracle (up to 11g at least) does not support this.
Why?

```
-- Valid
insert into some_table (magic) values (42);

-- Invalid
insert into some_table (magic) values (42), (666);
-- --> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: There's no a valid reason

Answer (score 3):

The plain answer is that not all RDBMSes support all of the various ANSI standards. Oracle just happens to not support this particular part of it.

Oracle does however support `INSERT ALL INTO`.

By the way, an example of `insert into dual` is terribad - You can break older versions of Oracle by doing an `INSERT` into `DUAL`.

Comment: Seems legit, it's just it soon is 2014 so I thought there might be a good reason why not. In the end, why are there even standards if such big players don't care about them...

Comment: At the risk of being flagged, my rant: I'm more and more disenchanted by the cr*p we put up with from Oracle: loads of poorly implemented features with many obscure bugs. In my experience PostgreSQL is technically a much better DBMS and more things just work. If you have the chance, jump ship.

Comment: Yeah, see that recent Materiaised View question, it's a fine example!